# What is missing (if anything) from this SQL statement?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS yr, count(*) AS users_count 
FROM users;
```

I'm new to SQL (so new that I can't find anything wrong with this). There may not be, and it may be a trick question. Would appreciate feedback!

Comment: The title is not the right place to ask the question and share the code. Can you please move if to the question body? You should also explain why you expect to find something wrong.

Comment: Is it MySql or SQL Server? Tag the server youi're really using.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Group BY" function too, because you use COUNT function with an another column.

For example:
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS yr, count(*) AS users_count FROM users group by YR;

Comment: You can't group by "YR", because "YR" doesn't exist in users (table)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Then I think, it should work:  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS yr, count(*) AS users_count FROM users group by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at);